# Object with an array of itself

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class like so

```
public class Cell{    
    static{
        int x;
        int y;
        Cell[]  cells = new Cell[10];
    }
}
```

Is that legal or the correct way to think about it? Have a class contain an array of itself (this is something possible in C).

Is this the right way to think about it from a design perceptive? Would it be better to have a Cell class and then a Cells class?

Comment: Sure, a class can have instances of its own type as members.  That's how linked lists and trees are implemented in Java - see the [Entry](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.Entry) class for example.

Comment: What is your question? Also, `static` != `struct`... so your fields there are only in scope to the static block.

Comment: What does "only in scope to the static block" mean?

Comment: @Morki See also [Section 8.7 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your class were to contain an array of itself, it is more likely to look like this:

```
public class Cell {    
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Cell[] cells;

    // constructors, getters, setters, etc
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly legal for a class to have a field whose type is an array with a component type that matches the enclosing class' type.  However, I would suggest making the field a class instance variable as opposed to a static field.

```
public class Cell{    

        private int x;
        private int y;
        private Cell[]  cells = new Cell[10];
}
```

A static field is a member of the class and each instance of the class will have refer to the same `Cell[]` instead of having their own distinct `Cell[]`.

Comment: Ah! So the cells array will be the same fir all 10 elements but they will each have their own x and y. Is that right?